# Pytorch torchvision.transforms execute randomly?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

I am doing this transformation:

```
self.transform = transforms.Compose( {
            transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225))
        } )
```

and then

```
image = Image.open(img_name)

if self.transform:
    image = self.transform(image)
```

this works for the first epoch then how the hell it crashes for the second epoch?
why the f `normalize` getting `PIL-image` and not `torch.tensor`? is the execution of each transforms Compose items random?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ubuntu/projects/ssl/src/train_supervised.py", line 63, in
>
> main()   File "/home/ubuntu/projects/ssl/src/train_supervised.py", line 60, in main
> train()   File "/home/ubuntu/projects/ssl/src/train_supervised.py", line 45, in train
> for i, data in enumerate(tqdm_):   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tqdm/std.py",
> line 1195, in **iter**
> for obj in iterable:   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py",
> line 530, in **next**
> data = self._next_data()   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py",
> line 1224, in _next_data
> return self._process_data(data)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py",
> line 1250, in _process_data
> data.reraise()   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_utils.py",
> line 457, in reraise
> raise exception TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0. Original Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 287, in _worker_loop
> data = fetcher.fetch(index)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in fetch
> data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]   File
> "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 49, in 
> data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]   File "/home/ubuntu/projects/ssl/src/data_loader.py", line 44, in
> **getitem**
> image = self.transform(image)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 95, in **call**
> img = t(img)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
> line 1110, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 270, in forward
> return F.normalize(tensor, self.mean, self.std, self.inplace)   File
> "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch-1.11.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 341, in normalize
> raise TypeError(f"Input tensor should be a torch tensor. Got {type(tensor)}.") TypeError: Input tensor should be a torch tensor.
> Got <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python set iteration order is not deterministic. Kindly use list instead ([] rather than {}).